# Keeping colors with white light

Tags: texturing, materials, light

I want to visualize a design project - a user interface, in a more fun way, and this is what I’ve got so far.

[image]

The problem that I can’t solve is that the light makes all colors go whiter and more bland. So right now the white isn’t white enough, the blacks aren’t black enough and the colors also turn too white. I turned "Specular" down to 0, which makes it slightly better, but I think it also makes the whites slightly grayer. Probably a basic question, but I'm new to Blender and I can’t find the answer. Does anyone know what I can do to solve this? Thank you.